# Does Tapper ever get outside his game?

Tags: disney, wreck-it-ralph

in Wreck it Ralph we see other characters leaving their game to do one thing or another. Like when Ken and Ryu from street fighter say they are going to Tapper's for a drink at the 2:00 minute mark.

As you can see below, a lot of characters are sitting in Tappers after hours and Tapper has to serve them drinks.

So it seems that poor old Tapper is in his game 24 hours a day, that is if the patrons stay until morning drinking. Anyone know if he ever gets out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tapper is seen attending Felix and Calhoun's wedding (on the groom's side, obviously) so it's pretty clear that he can leave his game.

The question of whether he does so *regularly* is unknown, but most sprites seem pretty content to stay in their own games out of hours.

[image]